# Changing interface orientation of parentviewcontroller

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a ViewController1 on iPad which presents another ViewController2 modaly using presentModalViewCotroller.

```
UIViewController* viewController2 = [[VideosViewController alloc] init];
viewController2.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
[self presentModalViewController:viewController2 animated:YES];
[viewController2 release];
```

But the ViewController2 has some parts that are semi translucent. So with the ViewController 2 already on screen, if i rotate the device 90 degrees, the Interface Orientation of ViewController2 changes appropriately, but the orientation of the Viewcontroller1 which is still visible in background does not change. I want the ViewController1 to change its Interface orientation along with ViewController2. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: hi, did you got this working. Let me know how to if you got it.

Comment: @Mohan look at my answer to this question below. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that it would have been much better if i simply used the UIModalPresentationFormSheet modalPresentationStyle on viewController2 because semi translucency that i was trying to achieve was anyway similar to form sheets. What I mean by this is that a viewController2 presented as form sheet also rotates the presenting viewController1 which is still visible in the background.